# Converting Option[T] to Option[U] in Scala

Tags: scala, syntax, functional-programming

Suppose we have an Option[String], and if there is Some(string) in there, we want to turn it into an Int to .toInt.  I would do the following:

```
val foo: Option[String] = Some("5")
val baz: Option[Int] = foo match {
    case Some(thing) => Some(thing.toInt)
    case None => None
}
```

This works great.  However, it seems extremely verbose and like a lot of work.  Can anyone show me a simpler way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: This feature can be abstracted: it is called 'Functor' . The functor type class may work with it's respectively instances such as : List, Tree, Option etc. It's quite a powerful concept if you start using it with a type class based approach.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems that you need to `map`:

```
val baz = foo map (_ toInt)
```

`Option` type support many collection operations (like `map`, `filter`, etc.) and a lot of nice helpful functions. Just take a look at scaladoc:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/scala/Option.html

Also this cheat sheet can be helpful:

http://blog.tmorris.net/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 10):

All you need is `foo.map(_.toInt)`